# Suppose that $G$ is a transitive permutation group of degree 12 and order $95,040 = 12\times 11\times10\times9\times8$. Prove that $G$ is simple.

Tags: group-theory

I've question on the problem 8C.3 from Isaacs's Finite Group Theory:

> Suppose that $G$ is a transitive permutation group of degree 12 and
> order $95,040 = 12\times 11\times10\times9\times8$. Prove that G is
> simple.

The hint on the book says:

> Show that $G$ must be 2-transitive, and that a nonidentity proper normal
> subgroup would have to be regular. Observe that a group of order 12
> can never be a minimal normal subgroup of any group.

I've shown that $G$ is 2-transitive. So the key question now is that how to show that a nonidentity proper normal subgroup of $G$ is regular.

If $G$ has two distinct minimal normal subgroups, then I know that they're regular.(See 8B.3 from Isaacs's Finite Group Theory). So we may assume that $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup $N$. Since $C_G(N)$ is semiregular, hence we may also assume that $N$ is non-abelian. But I have no idea now.

Comment: The fact that $N$ is regular follows immediately from Exercise 8C.2 (from which it follows that the point stabilizer in $G$ is simple).